# add class to child of this

Tags: jquery, addclass

This code is not working. `this+'>a'` isn't a valid syntax.
So, how can I add/remove a class in a child of `this`? In this case an `a` element.

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
        $("nav.menu>ul>li").hover(
            function () {
               $(this+'>a').addClass("hover_triangle");//error
            },

            function () {
               $(this+'>a').removeClass("hover_triangle");//error
            });
    });
```

I can't do `nav.menu>ul>li>a` because will select all `a` elements in menu.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$(this).children('a').addClass('hover_triangle');
```

and with the full code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('nav.menu>ul>li').hover(function() {
       $(this).children('a').addClass('hover_triangle');
    },function() {
       $(this).children('a').removeClass('hover_triangle');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('a', this)` allows you to look only inside of the `this` object

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("nav.menu>ul>li").hover(
        function () {
           $('a', this).addClass("hover_triangle");//error
        },

        function () {
           $('a', this).removeClass("hover_triangle");//error
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.find()`

```
$(this).find('> a').addClass("hover_triangle");
```

This will only access the immediate child elements of `nav.menu>ul>li`

[**CHECK FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CfQkB/)

If you want to just select the immediate children `.find('a')`  will get even the nested anchors.. To avoid that you need to use either `.find('> a')` or `.children('a')`

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).find('a').addClass('hover_triangle')` - more common way bacause it is not necessary to be a direct child

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods to search for descendents of `this` . Most have replied with `find()`(and it is easier to read) but a jquery selector also can have a second arfument which is `context`.

`$('a', this)` is another syntax and is the same as `$(this).find('a)` . Internallly jQuery will take the first case and use `find()` anyway, but the syntax is valid and many use it

API Refrence: 
**[jQuery( selector [, context] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)**